# Recover Visual Studio project from AWS Beanstalk Instance

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I had a Visual Studio project running on a Windows partition on my MacBook Air. I mistakenly deleted the Windows partition and consequently the Visual Studio project was also gone.

I had deployed the project to Amazon Web Services(AWS) before this happened. Is there anyway I can recover the project from AWS console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recover your project from one of your EC2 instances using the following steps:

1. RDP into one of the instances of your Beanstalk environment

   - go to the EC2 console page
   - locate the instance
   - click "Connect" to determine how to connect via RDP to your instance
2. Once connected to your instance through RDP, locate your project code, create a zip file. The project code is usually located at `C:\cfn\ebdata`
3. upload the code to S3 (you would need to run `aws configure` on the instance)
   (4. undo `aws configure` if necessary)
4. On your computer, download the project code from S3.
5. It's possible that there are files extraneous to your project code such as Beanstalk hooks and so on, which you might need to delete.

Comment: In step 2, how do I locate the project source code?

Comment: Updated detail.

Comment: For a .NET project, all `cs` files including controllers will be compiled into DLL files. To get the `cs` files; install **JetBrains dotPeek**, upload the *bin* folder and get your `cs` files by exploring through it.